# 19.04 - Cannot access Windows file shares

Tags: networking, server, samba, sharing

I have Ubuntu 19.04 installed and have a server running Windows 10 Pro, on which I have shared 2 folders (from an external USB), by right clicking folder, going to Share, and then giving  'Everyone' Read/Write access.

On Ubuntu machine, when I click Other Locations > Windows Network, I get the following error

> Unable to access location Failed to retrieve share list from server :
>   no such file or directory

When I try using Ctrl+l and input

> smb://192.168.1.11/share_name

*(Note, I have the same problem  here whether I use the IP address above, or the hostname of the Win 10 machine)*

I am presented with a log in box which says "Connect AS : Anonymous / Registered User.

Anonymous does not work, when I click Registered User and input my credentials

Username : My Microsoft account email address as linked to the single Windows 10 user account on the Win 10 machine 
Domain : 'WORKGROUP' (left at default) 
Password : the password linked to the MS account for Username

When I click Connect, nothing happens, the windows goes back to the default 'Anonymous' option but with everything greyed out.

I can ping the server from the Ubuntu client.

I have checked using apt list and samba packages seem to be installed.

The following command shows the server correctly and its NETBIOS name, so the Ubuntu machine can definitely see it

> nbtscan -v 192.168.1.0/24

The only other thing I have different on the Ubuntu machine is that it is set up to use DNS over HTTPS, so the DNS server in network settings is 127.0.0.1 (I cannot recall the command line tool I used for this, I did a sudo systemctl and checked all live .services but nothing jumped out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to install the cips-util packages and it then let me mount via CLI, I never got the dreadfil GNOME one working.

Answer (score 1):

> when I click Registered User and input my credentials
>
> Username : My Microsoft account email address as linked to the single
>   Windows 10 user account on the Win 10 machine Domain : 'WORKGROUP'
>   (left at default) Password : the password linked to the MS account for
>   Username
>
> When I click Connect, nothing happens, the windows goes back to the
>   default 'Anonymous' option but with everything greyed out.

Let's say my email address / Windows account is: mork@ork.com. When you use Connect to Server:

```
USERNAME: mork
DOMAIN:   ork.com
PASSWORD: nanunanu
```

Comment: Thx, I did not try this, the cips util package install worked in the end,, albeit only frtom CLI.. I've since reformatted due to other frustrations.. I can see myself going back to (awful awful) Windows